# Magento 2: Missing required argument $mainTable from Model\ResourceModel\Deal\Grid\Collection

Tags: php, magento2.2.2

Missing required argument $mainTable from Model\ResourceModel\Deal\Grid\Collection

But I check my all file and all code working fine but this error show on dashboard.

Comment: Please post your question with what you have done so far

Comment: when i installed extension it's some functionality working fine and some are not and show this error.

Comment: On which page you are getting this error

Comment: @Shweta Khattar Are you find the solution for this error? Because i am also stuck in this same error. If someone knows the proper solution post here.

Answer (score 3):

I think this issue is in any Deal module, I am just guessing from file's namespace, Go in your module's di.xml file and do this

```
<type name="Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Deal\Grid\Collection">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">custom table name</argument>
        <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Deal</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Might be mainTable argument is missing so I just added this. Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: I already add this

Comment: you need to update your question so that everyone can check what you have done so far

Comment: Hi @RamkishanSuthar, I already do this. But, still this error display. Can you please give me solution?

Comment: Can you please help me here? https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/263108/60509

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the below steps to fix the same:

1- Add the below lines in your di.xml file.

```
<type name="Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Deal\Grid\Collection">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">your_table_name</argument>
        <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Deal</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

2- Then run below commands:

```
bin/magento cache:flush
bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Hope It will help.

Answer (score 0):

If this happens in a module installed from composer, it can help to remove your vendor folder and run composer install and setup:upgrade again.
I had this problem myself after running composer install with --prefer-source flag.